# Centering multiple text with flexbox

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

How do I centering multiple text to the middle with flexbox. `Margin: auto;` and `text align: right;` does not worked.

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/L5mgy1sj/28/

I need `very long text 2` and `very long text 3` sit in the middle maybe with a margin of `5px;` to separate them;

Full view:
http://jsfiddle.net/L5mgy1sj/28/show

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin:auto` like this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.flex-item {
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: pink;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .flex-container {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-item:nth-child(n) {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"> text 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item"> text 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item"> text 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item"> text 4</div>
</div>
```